# Creating a cross platform app that retrieves info from an online azure database in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, azure, cross-platform

I am making a sermon app for a pastor as a small project. The way the app works is that all his sermons and info about it like date, topic, etc is stored in an online database, then the user with the app would be able to scroll through all the sermons listed by title, click it, and open the full sermon. I can design the UI and local code for that fine, where I ran into problems was the backend.

The app is meant to retrieve this sermon info from the backend that way the actual application is lightweight.

I'm using this site to help me with the backend:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk

I just wanted to know if I was on the right track, is the site I'm using right for this project? and what else do I need? and how exactly should I go about this?

Comment: Well, there really is no "right track" - whether you use Azure's mobile apps or take a different approach. Lots and lots of ways to solve such a challenge. Unfortunately this type of question is off-topic for StackOverflow (and tutorial recommendation questions are also off-topic). Now, if you have a specific issue with your app / program, then you should post that and ask specific questions. Note: There's plenty of documentation around Azure's mobile apps, within easy reach (of a search engine).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'm sorry, I'll try to ask more specific questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two services that I would look at.  The first is Azure Mobile Apps, but that has a limited text field.  That means you would likely have to store the text of the search somewhere else (blob storage, for example) for retrieval.

The second is Azure Search (which, like Mobile Apps, has a free tier for you to try out).  Azure Search can handle bigger files, but is a pain to update the content.  If you are uploading the sermons outside of the app (in a backend process), then this won't be an issue.

I cover both situations in my book - http://aka.ms/zumobook - Search is covered in Chapter 7 and Mobile Apps are covered in Chapters 1-4.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm checking the book out now. I appreciate the help, this is all fairly new to me

Comment: Not sure why you accepted this answer: Azure Search isn't a database. And the poster of this answer is promoting his book. And Mobile Apps? that's one of *many* approaches.